# ListView in android studio

Tags: listview, android-studio

I am beginner in android,
and I want to integrate this listview in my project in android studio. Is that possible? and how can I do it?

https://github.com/nolanlawson/SuperSaiyanScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Off course first of all you need to go to your build.gradle(app) and in compile section paste these line compile 'com.nolanlawson:supersaiyan-scrollview:1.2.0@aar' and use the above project code where you want !!!